# How to automate DIV height?

Tags: html

I am having a headache with this, I've search like everything and can't find a solution to this.

So I am trying to automate the DIV's height when I change the content of the DIV from another html-file, so it will match the other html-file's height.

This is the simplified html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function p01(){
    document.getElementById("change").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="01.html" ></object>';
    }
</script>

<script>
function p02(){
    document.getElementById("change").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="02.html" ></object>';
    }
 </script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="sidebar1">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li onclick="p01()"><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li onclick="p02()"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div style="width:75%; height:100%" id="change"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe remove the height style in the `#change` element?

Comment: Make them share a sigle `javascript` file so they will get the changes.

Comment: I've tried to remove the height parameters, but still not working properly.

Comment: This is the 01.html and 02.html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body style="overflow:hidden" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum...
</body>
</html>

Comment: Here is a demo of the problem. http://jeejee.netai.net/seppo/

Comment: It looks like this http://oi62.tinypic.com/mtnn0x.jpg
I managed to get the scrollbars away by changing the body overflow, but it didn't solve the size problem..

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
.sidebar1
{
height:auto;
}
```

Hope it will help you.
Regards.

Comment: No that didn't help, and in this demo, i have no style.css

Comment: The same problem seen here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_height
It's iframe, but the height can't be set by percent(%). How to make it automated height to fit the content?

Answer (score 0):

```
you can set the min height as well as height:auto,
so that you can set a particulate height to the container, and when the data in the container will get full it will take the auto height

class name{
min-height:768px;
height:auto;
}

check the jsfiddle for more understanding [jsfiddle][1]
```

Comment: Still not working, go ahead and check the actual site, the content should change what is clicked on the sidebar on left.
http://jeejee.netai.net/mrdb/

Comment: hi i just checked you site

Answer (score 0):

[image]

checkout the inspected area in the screenshot and update the height:value

Comment: you need to fix particulate height for eg. height:768px; overflow:auto;